# Data present in multidimensional array are not displayed correctly

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get the values from a Query String and add them to an array inside of an array. The output Query String is something like:
`add_to_cart.php?product_id=4&product_name=Pizza&quantity=1&additional_id[]=1&additional_quantity[]=3&additional_id[]=4&additional_quantity[]=5`
I'm getting each `additional_id` and `additional_quantity` variables presents in the Query String with the code below. I compare each of the `additional_id` with the IDs that I have in database table *additionals* and insert all into an array. The following code exists in my file **add_to_cart.php** file:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        $columns = array
        (
            'product_id_session' => $product_id_session,
            'product_id' => $product_id,
            'product_name' => $product_name,
            'product_price' => $product_price,
            'quantity' => $quantity,
            'additionals' => array()                        
        );
        if(isset($_GET['additional_id']) && $_GET['additional_id'] != "")
        {
            foreach($_GET['additional_id'] as $additional => $value)
            {
                $additional_id = $value;
                if(isset($_GET['additional_quantity'][$additional]))
                {
                    $additional_quantity = $_GET['additional_quantity'][$additional];
                    if($additional_quantity <= 0 || $additional_quantity > 5)
                    {
                        $additional_quantity = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $sql2 = "SELECT additional_id, additional_name, additional_price FROM additionals WHERE additional_id LIKE '{$additional_id}'";
                        $stmt2 = $connection->prepare($sql2);
                        $stmt2->execute();
                        while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                        {
                            extract($row);
                            $columns['additionals'][]['additional_id'] = $additional_id;
                            $columns['additionals'][]['additional_name'] = $additional_name;
                            $columns['additionals'][]['additional_price'] = $additional_price;
                            $columns['additionals'][]['additional_quantity'] = $additional_quantity;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id_session] = $columns;
    }
    header('Location: products.php?action=added&product_name=' . $product_name);
}
```

Once everything is added in the `cart` SESSION, in the **cart.php** page I'm trying to show the products with their selected additionals and quantities with:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product)
{
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$product['product_name']}</td>";
        echo "<td>&#36;{$product['product_price']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$product['quantity']}</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        foreach($product['additionals'] as $additional)
        {
            echo "<p>{$additional['additional_quantity']}x{$additional['additional_name']} - {$additional['additional_price']}</p>";
        }
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

But I'm doing something wrong, I think these two codes are not working properly.
My output is embarrassed, something like this:
[image]

Am I doing it by the right way? Maybe I'm not looping right with `foreach`, or the additionals are not being added with success? Sorry for the mistakes, I never worked with multidimensional arrays before. Is there a way to do what I am intending to? Thanks!

Comment: try changing all your `$columns['additionals'][]...` to `$columns['additionals'][$additional]...`

Comment: @Sean Thanks man, very thanks! This did the trick! I'm trying to do this since last friday! A great hug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution as per the comments-
Your issue is caused by `$columns['additionals'][]` as it is causing each value to being added as its own array. This is solved by added `$additional` as the array key -

```
while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    extract($row);
    $columns['additionals'][$additional]['additional_id'] = $additional_id;
    $columns['additionals'][$additional]['additional_name'] = $additional_name;
    $columns['additionals'][$additional]['additional_price'] = $additional_price;
    $columns['additionals'][$additional]['additional_quantity'] = $additional_quantity;
}
```

or you could also do-

```
while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    extract($row);
    $columns['additionals'][] = array('additional_id' => $additional_id,
                                      'additional_name' => $additional_name,
                                      'additional_price' => $additional_price,
                                      'additional_quantity' => $additional_quantity);
}
```

Comment: Nice, but I need to use the first solution because the user may choose not add additionals. Thanks!